# Delete edittext value in the recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-edittext

Currently: i have a recycler view where it has delete button and an edit text for each item.

Each item in the recycler view contains edit text that the user can input.

The scenario is i have 4 item in the list resulting 4 edit text.

When i try to fill up edit Text in the item(n) and tried to delete
the item(n) and add again. The edit Text value in the edit text remains.

How can i clear the value of the edit text?

Here is my current code when i try to delete a specific item in the list:

```
  mHeaderText.remove(pos);
                ArrayList<Integer> temp  = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                for (int i = 1 ; mHeaderText.size() >= i ; i++) {
                    temp.add(i);
                    Log.d("ADDDING","ADDDING"+i);
                }
                mHeaderText.clear();
                mHeaderText.addAll(temp);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Where are you clearing your EditText?

Comment: i still dont have code for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code ..
In adapter class in onBindView method when you perform click event then set edittext value as null.

```
edittext.setText("");
```

and if your edittext box in activity layout then make interface into adapter class and handling click event like this way...

```
OnItemClick onItemClick;

public void setOnItemClick(OnItemClick onItemClick) {
    this.onItemClick = onItemClick;
}

public interface OnItemClick {
    void getPosition(String data); //pass any data to shared it.
}
```

after that..

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    // below code handle click event on recycler view item.
    final String data = mStringList.get(position);
    holder.textView.setText(data);
    holder.firstButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onItemClick.getPosition(data); // shared data.
        }
    });
}
```

after that in activity adapter bind into recycler view it means adapter not null then called below line..

```
        adpater.setOnItemClick(new RecyclerViewAdpater.OnItemClick() {
        @Override
        public void getPosition(String data) {
            // hear perform any operation.
            editTextbox.setText("");
            adpater.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
edittext.setText("");
```

to clear text where edittext is reference to EditText. Since you haven;t posted complete code so i can guide to this only. If you provide more code, then I can help you more.

Answer (score 0):

One thing is sure. You will need to use

`edittext.setText("")` to clear the value.

But you need to be careful. You need to keep this as the first line in your delete row function, i.e. before you are removing that edittext item from your list.

Here is my code: I have placed the "remove row" function inside onBindViewHolder() method of Recyclerview Adapter.

```
holder.delImgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
//               You need to place it in the start
                holder.editText.setText("");
                // Remove the item on remove/button click
                myArrayList.remove(position);
                notifyItemRemoved(position);
                notifyItemRangeChanged(position, myArrayList.size());
                Toast.makeText(context, "Removed : " + position +" item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```